# What did it mean to be “declared infamous”?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-history, murder, appeal

According to Wikipedia, in [Ashford v. Thornton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashford_v_Thornton),

> If the plaintiff said the word craven ("I am vanquished") and gave up the fight, he was to be declared infamous, deprived of the privileges of a freeman, and held liable for damages to his opponent.

What would have been the procedure, and more importantly, the implications, of being declared “infamous”?

Comment: [Infamy! InfamyI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XP4d4EKT4U&t=83s)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Infamy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infamia) was a declaration that generally stripped a person of his legal status. This could include a loss of rights to contract, to testify in court, to vote, to serve in the military, to speak in public, etc.

Comment: Is infamy synonymous with outlawry then, or is that a further step?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I believe that's another step down the road.